# I can't get DeepBeliefTrainer to work with FeedForwardNetwork in Pybrain

Tags: python

Please help. I have been trying to use the DeepBeliefTrainer with a simple Deep Neural Network to no success. I am using the DeepBeliefTrainer available here: http://tinyurl.com/jeexh5g

I am getting the following error:
File "...\pybrain\structure\modules\module.py", line 104, in activate
assert len(self.inputbuffer[self.offset]) == len(inpt), str((len(self.inputbuffer[self.offset]), len(inpt))) 
AssertionError: (2, 1)

Below is my code:

```
ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)
ds.addSample([0,0],[0])
ds.addSample([0,1],[1])
ds.addSample([1,0],[1])
ds.addSample([1,1],[0])

n = FeedForwardNetwork()
no_neurons_hidden_layers = int(round(0.6 * ds.indim))
# creating layers
bias = BiasUnit(name='bias')
inLayer = LinearLayer(ds.indim,name='visible')
hiddenLayer1 = TanhLayer(no_neurons_hidden_layers,name='h1')
hiddenLayer2 = TanhLayer(no_neurons_hidden_layers,name='h2')
hiddenLayer3 = TanhLayer(no_neurons_hidden_layers,name='h3')
outLayer = SoftmaxLayer(ds.outdim,name='out')

# adding layers to modules
n.addInputModule(inLayer)
n.addModule(bias)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer1)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer2)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer3)
n.addOutputModule(outLayer)

# connecting layers to each other
inLayer_to_hidden1 = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer1)
bias_to_hidden1 = FullConnection(bias, hiddenLayer1)
hidden1_to_hidden2 = FullConnection(hiddenLayer1,hiddenLayer2)
hidden2_to_hidden3 = FullConnection(hiddenLayer2,hiddenLayer3)
hidden3_to_outLayer = FullConnection(hiddenLayer3,outLayer)
bias_to_outLayer = FullConnection(bias, outLayer)

#add connections
n.addConnection(inLayer_to_hidden1)
n.addConnection(bias_to_hidden1)
n.addConnection(hidden1_to_hidden2)
n.addConnection(hidden2_to_hidden3)
n.addConnection(hidden3_to_outLayer)
n.addConnection(bias_to_outLayer)

#sort modules
n.sortModules()

#make a Deep Belief Network
cfg = RbmGibbsTrainerConfig()
cfg.maxIter = 3
dbn = DeepBeliefTrainer(n,ds,epochs=50,cfg=cfg, distribution='bernoulli')
dbn.train()
```

Many thanks for any help.